# Append data from div to link url

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I am trying to have a `div` element on every page of my site that will contain the product number and then have a link that will put that number at the end.
For example,

```
<div id="productnumber">01101</div>
<a href="purchaseurl">https://example.com/#</a>
```

Then put the contents of the element with id *"productnumber"* after the # of the link.

Any idea if this is possible? Since this would make life easier than editing all existing pages and their respective `php` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). You could use some inline JS and append it to the href-Attribute (which should be were `id="purchaseurl"` is now)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple script to all your pages.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   var productNumber = document.getElementById('productnumber').textContent;
  
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href~="purchaseurl"]'), function(link) {  
     // if you want to change the link
     var currentHref = link.getAttribute('href');
     link.setAttribute('href', currentHref + '#' + productNumber);
     // if you want to change anchor text 
     var currentText = link.innerHTML;
     link.innerHTML = currentText + productNumber;
   });
});
```

```html
<div id="productnumber">01101</div>
<a href="purchaseurl">https://example.com/#</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), and [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).

```js
var data = document.getElementById('productnumber'),
    url = data.nextSibling.nextSibling;

url.innerText += data.innerText;
```

```html
<div id="productnumber">01101</div>
<a href="purchaseurl">https://example.com/#</a>
```